# Retrieve Largest Value On Iterators

Tags: c++, std, heapsort

I have three random-access iterators `parent`, `child1`, and `child2`, which point to certain values in a permuted array. (Context: I'm implementing heapsort; those iterators comprise a binary subtree).

I need to determine the iterator, which has the largest referenced value (to maintain the max-heap property of the heap). So, if `*parent` is the largest, return `parent`, if `*child1` is the largest, return `child1`, etc.

Pseudocode:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto iterator = std::max({ parent, child1, child2 });
```

`iterator` is now the iterator whose *underlying value* is the greatest.

The problem is that using this literal pseudocode, `std::max` would compare the iterators *itsself* here, not their referenced values. I could do `std::max({ *parent, *child1, *child2 })`, but it returns `decltype(*parent)`, so how would I get the iterator back from there?

I know it's trivially feasible using some `if`s, but isn't there some more elegant way? Does the standard library have something there? I tried several things, but they all seem bulky and inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't consider `std::max` with a custom comparator bulky, here it is:

```
auto iterator = std::max({ parent, child1, child2 },
                         [](auto it_a, auto it_b) { return *it_a < *it_b; });
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::max` accepts a comparison function object:

```
auto iterator = std::max({ parent, child1, child2 },
                         [](const auto& a, const auto& b){
    return *a < *b;
});
```

---

Although, you may prefer to refactor into some re-usable functional parts:

```
template<class Fun>
auto indirect_args(Fun&& fun = {}) {
    return [fun = std::forward<Fun>(fun)](auto&&... args) {
        std::forward<decltype(fun)>(fun)(
            *std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

auto iterator = std::max({ parent, child1, child2 },
                         indirect_args<std::less<decltype(parent)>>();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

since [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) has an overload for a custom comparator, you could do:

```
auto cmp = [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return *lhs < *rhs; };
auto iterator = std::max({ parent, child1, child2 }, cmp);
```